# Unable to add a category to a CPArrayController (cappuccino)

Tags: categories, cappuccino

I'm trying to add a method to the CPArrayController class via a category.
The template for adding reverse to the CPString works fine but I'm unable to add anything to the CPArrayController. While compiling I get the error

> SyntaxError: *** Could not find definition for class
>   "CPArrayController"

Here is my code:

```
@import <AppKit/CPArrayController.j>

    @implementation CPArrayController (Inserting)

    - (CPObject)insertAndReturn
    {
        if (![self canInsert]) return nil;
        var newObject = [self automaticallyPreparesContent] ? [self newObject] : [self _defaultNewObject];
        [self addObject:newObject];
        return newObject;
    }
    @end
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: How does this relate to PostgreSQL? Are you sure you used the correct subject?

Comment: oops… sorry the title was cached from a former question. Just corrected…Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPArrayController ist Part of AppKit.

So you need to import it, like :

```
@import <AppKit/CPArrayController.j>

@implementation CPArrayController (Inserting)

- (CPObject)insertAndReturn
{
    if (![self canInsert]) return nil;
    var newObject = [self automaticallyPreparesContent] ? [self newObject] : [self _defaultNewObject];
    [self addObject:newObject];
    return newObject;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi, oops I copied the wrong line (CPString instead of CPArrayController), I just corrected it. Actually even with the right import I get the compilation error. I placed the code block in the beginning of the AppController.j I really do not see what is wrong.

Comment: Just another question regarding to category (maybe it is the reason why I cannot get it work), what is the meaning of the "(Reversing)" in their category example "@implementation CPString (Reversing)" ? I proudly named it "(Inserting)" in mine but it is perhaps totally wrong…

Comment: The Description is only for you. (You can leave it blank and it change nothing)

But now i think you use an old Cappuccino Version, which doesn't include CPArrayController.

I upload an Example on Github with an actual Version of Cappuccino and it works like a charm : [CPArraycontroller Categorie Github](https://github.com/mafis/CPArraycontroller-Categorie-)

Comment: OK therefore it should be on my side… (or at least not a problem of the snippet itself). I will try to get the last version asap. Thank you for your help.